# pagination when reading mappings in solidity

Tags: solidity, mapping

I am trying to read a lot of data from a smart contract mapping, How can I include pagination when retrieving data through smart contract methods?

Answer (score 3):

It would not be efficient to do pagination in smart contract, it can be done on client side:

If you have mapping, most probably you have list of keys, something like:

```
uint count;
mapping(bytes32 => entry) entries;
bytes32[] keys;
```

Then you need:

- retrieve `count`
- calculate amount of pages from overall amount
- retrieve keys `keys[i], ...` for specified page
- retrieve entries `entries[keys[i]], ...` for specified page

Comment: It is possible to go out of gass when call whole bytes32[], even if few millions keys are in array?